Cron job to update permissions with a dynamic path structure
I have a 3rd party tool that requires a manual permissions modification on a file following an update (Dont even get me started on this, but it is what it is for now)
I would love to setup a cronjob that will update the permissions for me.
However, the path is going to be dynamic and will look something like this:
/foo/bar/v1.1.0/FILE_TO_MODIFY
Where the version number will change on each release. Old versions are kept in the same directory for rollback purposes
I have no idea how to solve this challenge. The idea of a symlink to "latest" came to mind but because I have no control over the folder structure of their application, I cant set this up

This has nothing to do with cron. cron just runs a command at a given time. You need to write a script for this anyway, just pick a scripting language that allows you to find the highest version number. There are many to pick, just use what you are comfortable with. Bash is probably among the worst choices.

Thanks, I understand that cron runs a script and cant do the work itself. Assumed thats implied :)
I dont want to have to start creating a complicated script to do this. Was wondering if theres a simpler (one liner) way that I cant think of.....

Well, if it really is a single file and you don't care if it is reset on older versions as well ... chmod [...] /foo/bar/*/FILE_TO_MODIFY would do it.

Thanks! It probably wont make a difference on the old files so it could be a good solution. Ill need to check with the 3rd party just to be sure

"Dont even get me started on this" - really I think we should. Sometimes a workaround is the right solution, but it is a VERY unusual case where it is not possible to avoid changing file permissions via a scheduled task (which even with a dynamic path is a relatively trivial problem).

....and bash might be a terrible solution but chmod a+r $( ls -d /foo/bar/v[0-9]* | sort -V | head -1)/*

That should be....chmod a+r $( ls -d /foo/bar/v[0-9]* | sort -V -r | head -1)/*

Oh, I wasn't aware sort has a version sort argument. There's always something to learn.

@symcbean I mean the entire concept that I have to change permissions for a 3rd party's deployment is a PITA. They should have the permissions change as part of the update cycle. I have brought it up with them but its not priority

No - that's still changing permissions (albeit at a more sensible time) instead of using a permissions model (groups, umask, setgid etc) that obviates this exercise.

I used @Gerald Schneiders solution:

Well, if it really is a single file and you don't care if it is reset
on older versions as well ... chmod [...] /foo/bar/*/FILE_TO_MODIFY
would do it.

